# Пропали данные профиля в Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

В общем: Windows 8.1 Есть пользователь User_X, всё было хорошо. Пользователь хранил рабочие и личные данные на рабочем столе и в папках C:/Users/User_X/*...(документы, изоображение, и т.д.).

Пришел другой дядя и добавил ещё одного локального пользователя в систему с именем User_Y. Зашел дядя под User_Y, там пару минут первоначальная настройка(подождите ещё не много, осталось совсем чуть чуть, и т.д.). Когда дядя залогинился под User_Y - он посидел пару минут и вышел. А когда попробовал залогиниться под User_X - тут он лицезрел первоначальную настройку(ту самую где, подождите ещё немного, осталось совсем чуть чуть и т.д.). Ну решил дядя подождать, что же это такое. Всё это длилось около получаса. А когда залогинилось - рабочий стол User_X оказался default. Его данные просто исчезли. Папки профиля(загрузки, документы, изоображения) - всё стало пустым. Данные пропали.

Дядя перезагружался, но данные не появлялись. Дядя с помощью recuva, R-Studio прогонял всеми возможными способами, но не одного намека на данные не было. Остались только ярлыки к этим данным в User_X\AppData\Roaming\Micros*\Win*\Recent.
В реесте нет "сид_пользователя".bak.

Куда пропали данные и как мне их восстановить?

Comment: Скорей всего `User_Y` просто решил немножко "подчистить систему", в том числе и от профиля `User_X` со всеми данными - вот и вся загадка. Никак данные не восстановить теперь.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov каким это таким образом User_Y решил "подчистить систему" ? И куда это они так делись,  что я их найти не могу?

Comment: Открыл "advanced system settings", в группе "user profiles" нажал кнопку "settings", выделил "User_X" и нажал "delete" - профиль стерся(windows с русским интерфейсом под рукой нет, поэтому всё на английском). Если `user_x` был залогенин в тот момент, то могли остатся какие-то файлы. А всякие "R-Studio" уже лет пять как бесполезны - у каждого первого SSD-шка, а на них данные сразу удаляются физически и безвозвратно(TRIM'ом), в угоду производительности.

Comment: Переносимые профили надо было использовать, либо бекапы делать

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Вы имеете ввиду, что дядя ручками стер профиль? Я и есть этот дядя. Диск HDD. 
Бэкапы и т.д. - надо было, другой дядя не позаботился.

Comment: Нет, не человек данные которого исчезли, а второй человек, которого вы называете "пришедший другой дядя"

Comment: @SergeyRufanov я понял, я вас запутал :)
Всё что описано в самом начале - в вопросе - так оно и было. Никаких намеренных чисток не производилось. Проблема возникла на программном или аппаратном уровне.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, если пользователь создался с обычными правами, то никакие шифт+делиты не снесут данные внутри чужого профиля.

Comment: @FenceCAD, винда на SSD или HDD?

Answer (score 1):

1 залогинется под администратором и поискать старые файлы.
2 поискать тайм метки, может где-то есть бэкап.
3 прогнать разные програмки по восстановлению данных после удаления(knoll on track ,ИТП).
4 не помогли предыдущие методы, тогда отдать жесткий диск спецам по восстановлению данных, и надеется что хоть что-то восстановится.
Удачи и терпения!

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что дядя за эти несколько минут вирусов натащил. Прогоните HDD антивирусами и несколько раз перезапустите. Исходный профиль должен выжить. Ещё, возможно, в результате действий дяди реестр замусорился. Посмотреть и почистить.